# How to assign more than one values to one variable

Tags: python-3.x

How do I assign more than one values to a single variable in python in if statement?
e.g...

```
If a='a','e','i',  etc
```

I have tried this before but it is not working.

Comment: why are you trying to assign values in an if statement

Comment: you could use a tuple or a list; `a=('a','e','i')` or `a=['a','e','i']`

Comment: You can't assign in an `if` statement (unless you are using `:=` in Python >= 3.8)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359)

Comment: If you want to check if `a` is equal to one of these values, you would write `if a in 'aei':`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are asking if `i` equals one element in a hardcoded list.

Try this code snipped:

```
if a in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: you must use 'i' or "i" inside i this code

Comment: no, if `a` is a variable which holds a char, no problem here.

Comment: use this code in IDE for run this error you see: NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: Then try to run `If a='a','e','i',` as asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is "How to check if a variable is equal to one or more values". If that is correct, then you use **in** operator. So your if statement will become:

```
if a in ['a','e','i']:
```

Comment: you must 'a' inside a for this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if "a" in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']:
     print("a" is in the Brackets)
```